# Probability distribution of randomly drawn summed ranks

Tags: probability, distributions, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, combinatorics

I have a sequence of *N* unique values which are ranked 1 to *N*.

A subset are those in positions 1 to *n* where *n* < *N*.

An ideal system of ordering would put the lowest ranks 1 to *n* in the first *n* positions.

e.g., *N* = 6, *n* = 3:

best cases:  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6     or equally, e.g.,:  3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4

worse cases: 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1    or equally, e.g.,: 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3

As a way of scoring the success of the ordering, I can sum the positions 1 to *n*, with a lower score being a greater degree of success. The number of unique scores is, I believe, given by *n* x (*N* - *n*) + 1. For high values of N, where the number of unique values is also high, the probabilities of achieving the different scores from random ordering is, I believe, approximately normally distributed.

However, for lower values of *N* where a normal approximation is not accurate, do the score probabilities follow a known distribution? I can calculate probability using Monte Carlo methods, but is there a formula?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this distribution is quite well known.

Imagine that you regard the first $n$ values as one sample and the remaining $m=N-n$ values as a second sample. Then your statistic is the sum of the ranks in the first sample.

This is one of the standard forms of the Wilcoxon rank sum test, and a linear shift of the Mann-Whitney test.

Not only can you find tables, but the distribution is built in to some packages.

For example, in R the functions `dwilcox`,`pwilcox`,`qwilcox`,`rwilcox` are available; they correspond to your statistic less the minimum possible value.

For example, with your $N=6,n=3$, to see the probability of getting a total $\leq7$, noting that $6$ is the smallest sum, you'd call `pwilcox(7-6,3,3)`
(the second and third arguments being the number in the first 'sample' and the remainder):

```
> pwilcox(7-6,3,3)
[1] 0.1
```

There are 20 (i.e. $6\choose 3$) combinations; two of them are $\leq 7$, which corresponds to the 0.1 there. (Another useful function in R is `combn` which will enumerate all the combinations or compute functions on them; for example `table(combn(6,3,sum))` will count the number of combinations at each sum.)

Here's an example of the `wilcox` functions in R with larger numbers:

[image]

(after this point the normal approximation starts to become quite handy except perhaps for the last couple of values at each end, which can be calculated by hand)

Comment: Fabulous. Thanks for your quick and comprehensive explanation and the R functions are useful too. A penny has dropped. Thanks again.